# How to include an iframe(without scroll) within masterpage (with scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWtq1.png)I've tried

```
scrolling="no" height=100%, overflow:hidden
```

it's not worked out.When i'm trying to add height in pixel like

```
style="height:4000px;"
```

iframe's background-image pixel get damaged.Looking for a solution without setting height. Please help me to solve this.

current Code
HTML  code

```
<div class="header_bar">
<div class="tab_active"   onclick="location.href='...'">Tab1</div>
<div class="tab_inactive" onclick="location.href='...'">Tab2</div>
<div class="tab_inactive" onclick="location.href='...'">Tab3</div>
</div>
<div class="iframe_container">
<iframe id="main_iframe" class="main_iframe" frameborder="0" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random">
</iframe>
</div>
<div class="header_bar">
<div class="tab_active"   onclick="location.href='...'">Tab1</div>
<div class="tab_inactive" onclick="location.href='...'">Tab2</div>
<div class="tab_inactive" onclick="location.href='...'">Tab3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html { height:100% }
body { height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; display:table;}
.header_bar {display:table-row; }
.iframe_container {height:100%; display:table-cell; }
iframe { height:100%; width:100%; display:block; }
```

I don't want the iframes scroll.

Comment: Could you post examples of your HTML & CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Add `scrolling="no"` to `ifram` tag like this :

```
<iframe id="main_iframe" class="main_iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"></ifram>
```

Comment: When i set scrolling ="no" iframe content hidden.

Comment: please add screenshot from your screen

Comment: i've attached the screenshot in the starting place of the question section. Please refer it.